# How to extract characters between two substrings using reg expression in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eg-My string is :

```
str1="[00:00:0.047] [TestRunner] [Main] [sleep_assoc] > [Iteration:0][00:00:0.063] [TestRunner] [Main] [sleep_assoc] > [!Iteration:0][00:00:0.063]"
```

I want to store all characters between `[Iteration:0]` & `[!Iteration:0]` to a string variable.

Comment: I don't suppose you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Hello, please provide an example of code you tried, and an example of input and the output you expect to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `.*?`, that matches all characters from `[Iteration:0]` till it find `[!Iteration:0]`:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = '[00:00:0.047] [TestRunner] [Main] [sleep_assoc] > [Iteration:0][00:00:0.063] [TestRunner] [Main] [sleep_as
   ...: soc] > [!Iteration:0][00:00:0.063]'

In [3]: m = re.search(r'\[Iteration:0](.*?)\[!Iteration:0]', s)

In [4]: res = m.group(1)

In [5]: res
Out[5]: '[00:00:0.063] [TestRunner] [Main] [sleep_assoc] > '
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex if the strings are so simple.

just do a `str1.split('[Iteration:0]')[1].split('[!Iteration:0]')[0]`

do you understand the code or shall I explain?